# for loop - iterate over specific elements

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I have the following data structure:

```
struct T
{
    std::string name;
    bool active;
};
```

Then I want to iterate over a vector of T but only for the active elements:

```
std::vector<T> myVector;
//fill vector
for(const auto& item: myVector)
{
    if(!item.active)
    {
        continue;
    }
    //do something;
}
```

Is there any feature which allows achieve that without using if and/or continue statements ?

Comment: No. I have to fill up the comment

Comment: It seems that you don't need `active` member to start with, according to what you ask.

Comment: Reverse the condition and "do something" inside the `if`?

Comment: ranges ts or boost filter_iterator

Comment: Assuming whatever you want to do can be written as an expression that yields a value, simply do   `item.active && expression_that_does_the_job()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just write wrapper iterator class and range class.

https://gist.github.com/yumetodo/b0f82fc44e0e4d842c45f7596a6a0b49

This is an example that implement iterator wrapping iterator.

---

Another way is using [Sprout](https://github.com/bolero-MURAKAMI/Sprout).

`sprout::optional` is container type so that you can write like below:

```
std::vector<sprout::optional<std::string>> myVector;
//fill vector
for(auto&& e : myVector) for(auto&& s : e)
{
    //do something;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to eliminate the check and not just hide it, then use a separate container to store the indices of elements where `active` is true, and replace the `for` loop with one that goes through all the indices in the other container.

Make sure that the indices container is updated every time the vector changes.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct T
{
    std::string name;
    bool active;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<T> myVector;
    using Index = decltype(myVector)::size_type;
    std::vector<Index> indicesActive;

    // ...

    for (auto index : indicesActive)
    {
        auto const& item = myVector[index];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Whether that's worth the trouble is hard to say without knowing the context of your problem.

---

Note that you can probably replace your `T` with `std::optional<std::string>` if your compiler already supports `std::optional`.